# What's a method that works exactly like Math.floorMod() but with floats instead of ints?

Tags: java, floating-point, modulo

Here's a set of inputs and outputs for [`Math.floorMod(x, 5)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorMod-int-int-) as an example.

```
int x;

inputs:
x = -15 | -14 | -13 | -12 | -11
    -10 | -09 | -08 | -07 | -06
    -05 | -04 | -03 | -02 | -01
    +00 | +01 | +02 | +03 | +04*
    +05 | +06 | +07 | +08 | +09
    +10 | +11 | +12 | +13 | +14

outputs:
   *+00 | +01 | +02 | +03 | +04
```

Just to be clear, all the inputs in column 1 result in the output in column 1 etc.

I want to be able to do this with floats too, but I've been unable to find any `Math.relevantMethod()` to help me with this. The idea is that all floats should map onto a span of floats between `0` and `y` (the second argument) Pac-Man style.

Comment: I highly suggest you use `double` rather than `float` as it has half a trillion times more precision.

Comment: When I say float, I mean floating-point, which double is. I use double in my solution below.

Comment: @PeterLawrey "half a trillion" I like that!

Answer (score 10):

## Solution

It took me a while to develop the algorithm  and work out all the kinks, but here it is. I dub it `floatMod()`.

```
double floatMod(double x, double y){
    // x mod y behaving the same way as Math.floorMod but with doubles
    return (x - Math.floor(x/y) * y);
}
```

Here's a table of inputs and outputs for floatMod(x, 2.0d) as an example. (I fixed the slight rounding errors for tidiness.)

```
double x;

inputs:
x = -4.0 | -3.6 | -3.2 | -2.8 | -2.4
    -2.0 | -1.6 | -1.2 | -0.8 | -0.4
    +0.0 | +0.4 | +0.8 | +1.2 | +1.6*
    +2.0 | +2.4 | +2.8 | +3.2 | +3.6
    +4.0 | +4.4 | +4.8 | +5.2 | +5.6

outputs:
   *+0.0 | +0.4 | +0.8 | +1.2 | +1.6
```

Here's some more examples.

```
floatMod(0.1f, 1f);     //returns: 0.1
floatMod(1.1f, 1f);     //returns: 0.100000024 aka 0.1 + 0.000000024
floatMod(2.1f, 1f);     //returns: 0.099999905 aka 0.1 - 0.000000095
floatMod(10000.1f, 1f); //returns: 0.099609375 aka 0.1 - 0.000390625

floatMod(0.1d, 1d);     //returns: 0.1
floatMod(1.1d, 1d);     //returns: 0.10000000000000009 aka 0.1 + 0.00000000000000009
floatMod(2.1d, 1d);     //returns: 0.10000000000000009 aka 0.1 + 0.00000000000000009
floatMod(10000.1d, 1d); //returns: 0.10000000000036380 aka 0.1 - 0.00000000000036380
```

---

## Algorithm explanation

If you're interested in how the algorithm `x - Math.floor(x/y) * y` works, I'll try my best to explain. Let's use the `floatMod(x, 2.0d)` example from above.

**First**, take this numberline of possible values for x:

```
                                ●------------------------○
       |                        |                        |                        |
-2.4 -2.0 -1.6 -1.2 -0.8 -0.4 +0.0 +0.4 +0.8 +1.2 +1.6 +2.0 +2.4 +2.8 +3.2 +3.6 +4.0 +4.4
```

The spaces between the vertical lines represent chunks of length y stacked side-by-side in both directions. The filled circle means inclusive, while the hollow circle means exclusive, and the ones illustrated above encompass chunk 0 represented by the dashed line.

**Next**, `x/y` (y = 2.0 in this case) takes a given position on the numberline x and gives what it is in terms of chunks. So, 2.0 is the end of chunk 0 and the beginning of chunk 1, so 2.0/y = 1.0.

We'll say x/y = c;

1.0/y → 0.5c as 1.0 is half a chunk
3.2/y → 1.6c
-2.4/y → -1.2c
etc.

**Next**, `Math.floor(c)` means whichever chunk we're in, reduce c to the beginning of said chunk. In other words, which one is x in?

0.5c → 0.0c
1.6c → 1.0c
-1.2c → -2.0c

**Next**, it multiplies the result by y again to get it back in terms of x.

0.0c * y → 0.0
1.0c * y → 2.0
-2.0c * y → -4.0

**Finally**, it just takes this value and calculates how far x is away from it, as in how far away is x from the beginning of the chunk it's in?

Another way of looking at it: It needs to subtract out the extra chunks in x, so it figures out how many chunks forward or backward x is from chunk 0 and removes that amount. This keeps it within the bounds of 0 and y.

1.0 - 0.0 → 1.0
3.2 - 2.0 → 1.2
-2.4 - -4.0 → 1.6

---

(Uhh... Ok so, after writing through most of the explanation for the algorithm, I realized there was a way to simplify it. After I did, I realized it's actually the exact same as the floorMod algorithm, just with floats. I'm here acting like some kind of savant who's discovered the unified theory of everything when all I did was take one extra step from what was right under my nose. I do promise that I racked my brain to develop this from scratch though.

The original algorithm I had was `-Math.floor(x/y) * y + x` which got pretty confusing to explain at a certain point. I'm still glad I wrote this though as I believe it's good information and it was a lot of fun.)

Comment: Can you add a comment on why you wouldn't use `x % y` ?

Comment: Sure. x % y behaves the exact same as my `floatMod()` for positive numbers, but very differently for negative numbers. Take `-3.4d % 2d` for example. One way of calculating the answer is this: *-3.4 / 2 = -1.7* (x/y) *chop(-1.7) = -0.7* (chop off the whole number leaving the decimal) *-0.7 * 2 = -1.4*  (ans*y). -1.4 is indeed the answer, but it's instead between -2 and 0. If I try to correct for this by adding y to the result, then it's almost the same. The difference is that the inclusivity of the chunk boundaries is reversed. e.g. `floatMod(-4d, 2)` = 0.0 whereas `(-4d % 2) + 2` = 2.0.

Comment: Read the documentation on [floorDiv](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorDiv-int-int-) and [floorMod](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorMod-int-int-) for hopefully a better understanding. The biggest difference seems to be in the floor and truncation rounding modes.

Comment: I made this algorithm a long time ago (along with integer variants before Java had them) and thought it was simple. I only had to satisfy the invariant `floorMod(x, y) + floorDiv(x, y) == x`, where `floorMod(x, y) := floor(x / y) * y` and with a single step of rearranging the solution showed itself. I came here because I hoped there would be a native implementation by now (there being Java 11 and all) but it's still the status quo.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems with using floating point esp for modulus is that you see significant representation errors. What you are better off doing is to round the result or the calculation so you get sane outcomes. A simple way to do this is to assume you only ever want N digits of precision e.g. 6.

```
public static double floorMod(double x, double y) {
    return Math.floorMod(Math.round(x * 1e6), Math.round(y * 1e6)) / 1e6;
}
```

for the examples above you get

```
floorMod(0.1f, 1f);     //returns: 0.1
floorMod(1.1f, 1f);     //returns: 0.1
floorMod(2.1f, 1f);     //returns: 0.1
floorMod(10000.1f, 1f); //returns: 0.099609 due to the limits of float.

floorMod(0.1d, 1d);     //returns: 0.1
floorMod(1.1d, 1d);     //returns: 0.1
floorMod(2.1d, 1d);     //returns: 0.1
floorMod(10000.1d, 1d); //returns: 0.1
```

Another approach is to specify the precision

```
public static double floorMod(double x, double y, double precision) {
    double factor = Math.round(1 / precision);
    return Math.floorMod(Math.round(x * factor), Math.round(y * factor)) / factor;
}

floorMod(10000.1f, 1f, 0.1); // returns 0.1
```

Comment: I see what you're saying. I wouldn't say this is the better solution in all circumstances though. It's only better if it matters that the answer is rounded. I just used nice round numbers in my examples for convenience. If say you wanted to wrap an angle between 0 and 2*pi, then you might want as many significant digits as you can get. It would probably be a good idea to do `theta = floatMod(theta, two*pi)` every time the angle changes so theta hopefully never skyrockets into super bad rounding territory. I like having your solution under my belt as well though. Thanks.

Comment: What is this 10000.1d? A new Java construct? Or C#?

Comment: Finally remembered.  "d" simply means double. So 10000.1d is identical to 10000.1. The d is just to emphasize it is a double, not a float.